# Having issue getting PHP to work in Amazon EC environment.. Works in subs not root

Tags: php

I am using Amazon EC to see if its prudent for me.. i have installed mysql and php as described : http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2011/03/getting-php-mysql-running-amazon-ec2/
  yet i can't seem to get php to work in root

Doesn't Work here:
http://ec2-184-73-71-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com/phpinfo.php

works here:
.../padmin/phpinfo.php

my httpd conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName dev1.xx.co
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

ideas?

Comment: doesn't work how? Not executed as PHP? Getting PHP error?

Comment: not executing as php as far as i can see

Comment: If it's not executing, you'd see the raw source code served up (either as text, or offered as a download).

Comment: Thanks mark. you can see the raw source here:   http://ec2-184-73-71-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: So for some reason your instance is configured to execute PHP in subdirectories, but not the document root. That's a very goofy configuration.

Comment: Marc, I just can't figure out where that is set..

Answer (score 0):

short_open_tag was set to off... by setting to on in php.ini .. it worked like a charm..